# imagine (someone/something) as or to be

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the difference between ***imagine someone/something as something*** and ***imagine someone/something to be something*** . Can I use them interchangeably?

Examples :

1-I imagine him as a distinguished old gentleman.

2-I think they imagine the company to be bigger than it is.

Answer (score 2):

To imagine someone **as** something is to imagine them being something other than they are -

> 1. verb If you imagine something, you think about it and your mind forms a picture or idea of it.

I imagined my father as Father Christmas - I had a mental image of my father dressed in a red costume, pretending to be Father Christmas.

To imagine someone **to be** something is to believe that they really are that thing.

> 2. verb
>      If you imagine that something is the case, you think that it is the case.

I imagined my father to be Father Christmas - I believed that my father really was Father Christmas.

[Imagine](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/imagine)

Comment: We came up with significantly different imagery (?!), but I think we're both singing from the same hymn-sheet here!

Comment: Whatever floats your boat...

Comment: or whatever tickles your fancy! :)

Comment: E.g. Santa's beard?

Comment: Steady on, tiger!

Answer (score 1):

There's definitely been a [usage shift over time...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=imagine%20it%20as%20a%2Cimagine%20it%20to%20be%20a&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimagine%20it%20as%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimagine%20it%20to%20be%20a%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

In many if not most contexts, the two forms are equivalent (though perhaps because I'm older, I'd normally favour ***to be***).

But to my mind, *to imagine X **as** Y* can more naturally imply *to construct an **imaginary** mental image of **X** having the attributes of **Y*** (whilst knowing perfectly well that X *isn't* actually Y). Conversely, *to imagine X **to be** Y* more naturally suits contexts where you *think* X truly is Y. Thus the following two examples represent the natural choices for the two senses...

> 1: *I imagine you **as** a leather-clad [dominatrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominatrix)*
>    - I know you're *not* a dominatrix (but I get a sexual kick out of *picturing* you as one).
>
> 2: *I imagine you **to be** a leather-clad dominatrix*
>    - It seems likely to me that you *are* a dominatrix (but I don't know this for certain).

Note that #2 [could also be expressed](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=imagine%20it%20as%20a%2Cimagine%20it%20to%20be%20a%2Cimagine%20it%20is%20a&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimagine%20it%20as%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimagine%20it%20to%20be%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimagine%20it%20is%20a%3B%2Cc0) more straightforwardly as...

> 3: *I imagine you **are** a leather-clad dominatrix*

Comment: Descriptions of performances of play or films often say things like "Joe Bloggs as King Lear", that is, Joe Bloggs playing the part of King Lear, and it seems comfortable to see 'imagine as' working like that, at least to me.

Comment: Yeah - if the description said "Joe Bloggs **to be** King Lear", I imagine that would pragmatically require a context where the performance / filming hasn't yet taken place (but when it *does*, it's known/expected that Joe will take the lead role).